# Is it possible to make the trunk in svn point to a branch (a la symbolic link)

Tags: svn, branch, symlink

Our svn-repositories usually consist out of several branches of which 1 is the 'live' version. Currently we make that one the trunk, but this has some drawbacks; everytime we migrate to a new branch, we have to rename the trunk to become a branch or delete it altogether and rename a branch to become the trunk. We would rather have no trunk at all, but then the developers have to do a new checkout (or a switch) every time we migrate. This is too error prone.
I was thinking that if we would be able to make the trunk to be just a kind of symbolic link to the live branch, then we would be able to solve this problem. We would just update the symbolic link when we migrate.
My questions are; is this possible and how? and is there another (maybe better) way to achieve what we want?

thanks,

Coen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delete the `trunk` folder and make it an *[external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals)*.

Comment: in this case we cannot checkout the trunk itself, only the root

Comment: @Coen: Then either `trunk` must either refer to every item in the branch individually or you learn to live with another level of indirection and `trunk/current` refers to the current branch with `trunk` otherwise being empty.